# Programatically reordering PDF content in layers (OCGs)

Tags: javascript, python, pdf

Here is a really simple problem that, somehow, does not seem to have a proposed solution yet.

I have a PDF document which has content arranged in layers like this:

```
<Layer 1>
    <Clip Group>
        <GraphicsPath>
        <GraphicsPath>
        <GraphicsPath>
        ...
        <CutPath>
        <CutPath>
        <CutPath>
        ...
```

Programatically, I want to reorder the content so it is organized like this:

```
<ThroughCut>
    <CutPath>
    <CutPath>
    <CutPath>
    ...
<Graphics>
    <GraphicsPath>
    <GraphicsPath>
    <GraphicsPath>
    ...
```

I have determined the layer structure using Adobe Illustrator. There, it is straight forward to create and rename layers, then drag objects around to get the right arrangement. However, I have struggled for days now finding a good way to do this programatically. It appears that `PyMuPDF` would be the right Python library for this, as it supports adding and setting layers and OCGs (I must admit I don't quite understand the difference), but I have played around with it for half a day now and I simply can't figure it out.

Solutions using Python and JavaScript are most appreciated, but I'll take anything that I can run from the command line on a UNIX machine at this point.

Comment: Optional content group is the PDF term, layer is the popular term for optional content. Do you want to reorder the actual page content or just the nodes in the optional content visual tree (the one that is displayed in Acrobat and lets you show/hide layers)?

Comment: Just the nodes. For simplicity's sake: so that Illustrator understand's it. In reality I'm formatting the PDF so it gets read properly by another software, but it is compatible with Illustrator.