# Export SVG to PDF with groups/layers intact

Tags: javascript, python, pdf, svg

I have an SVG object that looks like this:

[image]

Each of the inner `<g>` elements have `<path>`s in them.

I want to export this SVG to PDF so the groups translate to layers (OCGs), like this:

```
<ThroughCut>
    <Path>
    <Path>
    <Path>
    <Path>
<Graphics>
    <Path>
    <Path>
    <Path>
    <Path>
```

Yet any tool I have tried for this puts all objects in the same layer, and basically throws away information about groups.

Solutions in JavaScript or Python are preferred, but anything that executes from the command line on a UNIX machine will do.

Comment: Since SVG does not support optional content groups (aka layers) like PDF, there is no reason for a SVG to PDF converter to convert <g> tags to OCGs in PDF. But your problem here gives me a suggestion for a future feature in our product :)

Comment: @iPDFdev that's great news! Also have a look at this question I raised, concerning rearranging layers in PDF. If your product can do that I would definitely use it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68802965/programatically-reordering-pdf-content-in-layers-ocgs

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem as stated here, by following [this PyMuPDF issue](https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/issues/709) on Github.

Since I have control over the input SVG, I managed to solve the problem by parsing two SVGs to PDFs and combining them in separate layers of a new document. **This is what I'm doing**:

```
import fitz
from svglib.svglib import svg2rlg
from reportlab.graphics.renderPDF import drawToString

def svg_to_doc(path):
    """Using this function rather than `fitz`'  `convertToPDF` because the latter
    fills every shape with black for some reason.
    """
    drawing = svg2rlg(path)
    pdfbytes = drawToString(drawing)
    return fitz.open("pdf", pdfbytes)

# Create a new blank document
doc = fitz.open()
page = doc.new_page()

# Create "Layer1" and "Layer2" OCGs and get their `xref`s
xref_1 = doc.add_ocg('Layer1', on=True)
xref_2 = doc.add_ocg('Layer2', on=True)

# Load "layer_1" and "layer_2" svgs and convert to pdf
doc_1 = svg_to_doc("my_layer_1.svg")
doc_2 = svg_to_doc("my_layer_2.svg")

# Set the `page` dimensions. Note: for me it makes sense to set the bounding
# box of the output to the same as `doc_1`, because I know `doc_1` contains
# `doc_2`. If that were not the case, I would set `bb` to be a new
# `fits.Rect` object that contained both `doc_1` and `doc_2`.
bb = doc_1[0].rect
page.setMediaBox(bb)

# Put the docs in their respective OCGs
page.show_pdf_page(bb, doc_1, 0, oc=xref_1)
page.show_pdf_page(bb, doc_2, 0, oc=xref_2)

# Save
doc.save("output.pdf")
```

If I load "output.pdf" in Adobe Acrobat the layers show. Curiously, the same is not the case for Adobe Illustrator (here they are simply "Clip Groups"). Regardless, I believe this solves the problem as stated above.

[my_layer_1.svg](http://ix.io/3wlI)

[my_layer_2.svg](http://ix.io/3wlJ)

Answer (score 1):

My other solution, although correct, does not produce a PDF that is compatible with Adobe standards (for example, Illustrator will not see the OCGs as legitimate layers—although strangely, Acrobat will).

In case one needs to produce **a PDF that *is* compatible with Adobe standards**, and will be loaded correctly in Illustrator, another option is to use the Illustrator scripting API.

Here's a script that one can use to convert a loaded SVG file into a PDF with the desired layer structure.

```
/** Convert an open file in Illustrator to PDF, after removing the first layer.
 *  Useful for converting SVGs into PDFs, where it is desired that the first level
 *  `<g>` elements are converted to layers/OCGs in the exported PDF.
*/

// Select export destination
const destFolder = Folder.selectDialog( 'Select folder for PDF files.', '~' );

// Get the PDF options to be used
const options = getOptions();

// The SVG should have a single `Layer1` top layer...
const doc = app.activeDocument;
if (doc.layers.length == 1) {
    
    // ... remove it
    removeFirstLayer(doc)

    // Create a file pointer for export...
    var targetFile = getTargetFile(doc.name, '.pdf', destFolder);
    
    // ... and save save `doc` in the file pointer.
    doc.saveAs(targetFile, options);
}


/* --------- */
/* Utilities */
/* --------- */

function getOptions() {
    // Create PDFSaveOptions object
    var pdfSaveOpts = new PDFSaveOptions();
    
    // Set PDFSaveOptions properties (toggle these comment/uncomment)
    pdfSaveOpts.acrobatLayers = true;
    pdfSaveOpts.colorBars = true;
    pdfSaveOpts.colorCompression = CompressionQuality.AUTOMATICJPEGHIGH;
    pdfSaveOpts.compressArt = true; //default
    pdfSaveOpts.embedICCProfile = true;
    pdfSaveOpts.enablePlainText = true;
    pdfSaveOpts.generateThumbnails = true; // default
    pdfSaveOpts.optimization = true;
    pdfSaveOpts.pageInformation = true;
    // pdfSaveOpts.viewAfterSaving = true;
    

    return pdfSaveOpts;
}

function removeFirstLayer(doc) {
    // Get the layer to be removed
    var firstLayer = doc.layers[0];
    
    // Convert groups into new layers
    for (var i=firstLayer.groupItems.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        var group = firstLayer.groupItems[i];
        var newLayer = firstLayer.layers.add();
        newLayer.name = group.name;
        for (var j=group.pageItems.length-1; j>=0; j--)
            group.pageItems[j].move(newLayer, ElementPlacement.PLACEATBEGINNING);
    }
    
    // Move new layers to the document and remove `firstLayer`
    for (var i=firstLayer.layers.length-1; i>=0; i--)
        firstLayer.layers[i].move(firstLayer.parent, ElementPlacement.PLACEATBEGINNING);

    firstLayer.remove();
}

function getTargetFile(docName, ext, destFolder) {
    var newName = "";

    // Add extension is none exists
    if (docName.indexOf('.') < 0)
        newName = docName + ext;
    else
        newName += docName.substring(0, docName.lastIndexOf('.')) + ext;
    
    // Create file pointer
    var myFile = new File(destFolder + '/' + newName);
    
    // Check that file permissions are granted
    if (myFile.open("w"))
        myFile.close();
    else
        throw new Error('Access is denied');

    return myFile;
}
```

1. Put the script in a file that ends with `.jsx`, and place in inside your `Scripts` folder in Illustrator. Mine is located at `/Applications/Adobe Illustrator 2021/Presets/en_US/Scripts/svgToPDF.jsx`.
2. Restart Illustrator
3. Execute the script from the `File` > `Scripts` > `svgToPDF` menu item.

#### Drawbacks

- Illustrator costs money.
- You have to manually execute the `SVG` -> `PDF` conversion. Could be automated with AppleScript, but it's really not something you want to have running on a server.